# DDD - Entity creation business rule validation

Tags: php, oop

I have a business rule such as this :

> If a JobSeeker wants to apply to a Vacancy, make sure that the Resume used in application is completed and that JobSeeker hadn't
>   applied to that Vacancy already. If the condition is satisfied, then
>   the application will be written in a JobApplicatiion.

This is what I came up with :

**JobSeeker.php**

```
class JobSeeker {
    private $applications;
    private $resume;

    /** Other irrelevant props **/

    public function apply(Vacancy $vacancy, Resume $resume) {
        // Business rule #1
        if(!$resume->isCompleted()) throw new \Exception('Resume '.$resume->getTitle().' is incomplete.');

        // Business rule #2
        $alreadyApplied = array_filter($this->applications->toArray(), function(JobApplication $application) use($vacancy) {
            return $application->getVacancy() === $vacancy;
        });

        if($alreadyApplied) throw new \Exception('Vacancy '.$vacancy->getTitle().' is already applied');

        // If both rules passed, then create a JobApplication
        $application = new JobApplication($this, $vacancy, $resume);

        $this->applications->add($application);

        return $application;
    }
}
```

**JobApplication.php**

```
class JobApplication {
    private $applicant;
    private $vacancy;
    private $resume;

    public function __construct(JobSeeker $applicant, Vacancy $vacancy, Resume $resume) {
        $this->applicant = $applicant;
        $this->vacancy = $vacancy;
        $this->resume = $resume;
    }
}
```

If I was to expect that everyone would just use

```
$jobApplication = $jobSeeker->apply($vacancy, $jobSeeker->getResume());
```

Then there's no problem.

The problem arise when someone do this

```
$jobApplication = new JobApplication($jobSeeker, $vacancy, $resume);
```

The second example will bypass the business rule validation.

It did occurred to me to separate the rule checking to a different method :

**JobSeeker.php**

```
class JobSeeker {
    public function canApply() {
        // Here goes those 2 business rules mentioned
    }

    public function apply(Vacancy $vacancy, Resume $resume) {
        if($this->canApply($vacancy, $resume)) {
            return new JobApplication($this, $vacancy, $resume);
        }
    }
}
```

**JobApplication.php**

```
class JobApplication {
    public function __construct(JobSeeker $jobSeeker, Vacancy $vacancy, Resume $resume) {
        if($jobSeeker->canApply($vacancy, $resume)) {
            // Same as before
        }
    }
}
```

While the second approach guarantees the business rule constraint, it's very redundant and still does not provides the expected result.

```
$jobApplication = new JobApplication($jobSeeker, $vacancy, $resume);
```

I need an insight in this.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending how you do it you have 2 aggregate roots as I see it
`JobSeeker`
`Vacancy`

`Resume` is an like a profile for an user

Well DDD likes to uses services, for almost everything.

So we have the `JobSeekerApplicaitonService` this services will be used for the external world.

On the `JobSeekerApplicaitonService` I would add the method `apply`

```
public function apply(JobSeeker $jobSeeker, Vacancy $vacancy);
```

First we check if the bussiness rules are met.
ie.

```
$jobSeeker->getResume()->isCompleted();
```

This check throws an error if it is not completed.

Next we make another function at the `JobSeekerApplicaitonService` which checks if an JobSeeker already has applied, can also be used for the view to let the user already see he has applied for example.

```
public function hasApplied(JobSeeker $jobSeeker, Vacancy $vacancy);
```

But this method can now be used in our apply function

$this->hasApplied($jobSeeker, $vacancy);

Again throw an exception when already applied.

You can now savely reutrn the `new JobApplication`. Although I would say the `JobSeekerApplicaitonService` repository and create it there, so it is saved in the db because that is what an application service is, a delegator.

Code

```
class JobSeekerApplicaitonService {
    public function apply(JobSeeker $jobSeeker, Vacancy $vacancy) {
        if ($jobSeeker->getResume()->isCompleted()) {
            // throw exception
        } elseif ($this->hasApplied($jobSeeker, $vacancy)) {
            // throw exception
        }
        // save logic or something else you want
    }

    public function hasApplied(JobSeeker $jobSeeker, Vacancy $vacancy) {
        // your check, I would now use the JobApplicationRepository
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `new JobApplication(/**..**/)` ?

Comment: Would come at "// save logic or something else you want"

Comment: Still, how do you constraint people from just doing `new JobApplication()` in the controller? Is another validation inside the constructor needed?

Comment: You can't. But then again in the open world, everything after the ApplicationService (so the controller also) should have no access to the change methods of the entity. This way people can create the new JobApplication but can't add it to the `JobSeeker`, only via the `JobSeekerApplicaitonService` this can be done

Comment: Hmm.. So it's basically same as my first option only to move it to a service? In .Net I imagine of doing it with an internal constructor, is there another possible way in PHP?

Comment: You could make the `__construct` protected/private method. Then have a function on the class that constructs it. But in php there is no protected/private class if that is what you mean. Every class is available in the global scope

Answer (score 0):

Your first examples of JobSeeker & JobApplication are correct. The JobSeeker.apply method is acting as the factory for JobApplications:

```
job_application = job_seeker.apply(vacancy, resume)
```

Looks good.

The following statement, however, doesn't make much sense:

```
$jobApplication = new JobApplication($jobSeeker, $vacancy, $resume);
```

Considering the real world, have you ever seen a JobApplication randomly burst into existence out of thin air and land on your desk? I haven't :) In most cases, one entity is created from another:

```
employee = company.hire(person)
invoice = employee.create_invoice(customer, invoice_terms)
etc...
```

If you see an entity being 'new-ed' in a command handler, it should raise an eyebrow.